# Auto numbering to parent and child columns

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, ssrs-2008-r2, subreports

I am using SSRS 2012 for MS CRM report(FetchXML) which should get result as shown in below image : 
 [image]

 There are Name and Parent columns. Based on Parents, Names should be displayed and numbering should be exactly in same order. I can able to display same order except numbering by using sub report.

Note: Using FetchXML Query only.
Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for my question. You need to do grouping and use expressions as shown in following image. Hope this helps someone :)[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is using row groups.
Make a matrix with a single row group, and group on "Parent". Sort the matrix by name. Add the relevant columns. You'll end up with a table that looks very similar to what you want, except for the 1.0 and 1.1 columns. Those don't exist in your source table, so you'll have to add them yourself and just do some basic math to get the numbering right.

If your parents are not sorted in the source table, just add an "order by" clause to the FetchXML query to order by parent. This will ensure that the parent groups are in the right order. The matrix sort on name will ensure that within each group, the rows are sorted by name.